# Can not deploy JavaFX 2 application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have the project based on JavFX 2, it`s done and works perfect in Eclipse. Now i am trying to deploy it on computer(self-service,terminal,..). I have created jar file, but when i am trying to "java -jar myproject.jar" i take the following

```
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

UDT:
I think there is some problem with jfxrt.jar where javafx.application.Application class stored, in eclipse i added this jar in build path manually..

Comment: I think you are missing jfxrt.jar in your created jar file.

Comment: i added it and some necessary for javaFX application files in bin/lib/ext folders of the jre, i think java should find it..

Comment: I think you should include it with your jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 7, JavaFX is included with the JDK download but is not on the classpath (JavaFX is not part of the core libraries in Java 7). Have a look at the [tutorial on deployment](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm), which shows mechanisms for deploying a jar file that will work.

(In Java 8, JavaFX becomes part of the core libraries and will be included on the classpath, so your regular jar file may well work. There are still some cool things you can do with the proper deployment process, though.)